# Vagrant not adhering to static ip definition in vagrant file

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

Vagrant Version: 2.2.5
Provider: Hyper-V
OS: Windows 10, 1809

Upon specifying an ipv4 address in my vagrantfile, upon using "vagrant up" it does not assign it, it assigns another address

I've tried changing the address to different ranges, using different adapters etc. and still it does not honor what is specified within the Vagrantfile.

Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "kube-1" do |ctl|
        ctl.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1804"
        ctl.vm.hostname = "kube-1"
        ctl.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.18.72.210", bridge: "Default Switch"
        ctl.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
        ctl.vm.provider "hyperv" do |vb|
            vb.memory = 2048
            vb.cpus = 2
        end
    end
end
```

Output:

```
Bringing machine 'kube-1' up with 'hyperv' provider...
==> kube-1: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
==> kube-1: Verifying Hyper-V is accessible...
==> kube-1: Importing a Hyper-V instance
    kube-1: Creating and registering the VM...
    kube-1: Successfully imported VM
    kube-1: Configuring the VM...
==> kube-1: Starting the machine...
==> kube-1: Waiting for the machine to report its IP address...
    kube-1: Timeout: 120 seconds
    kube-1: IP: 172.18.72.197
==> kube-1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    kube-1: SSH address: 172.18.72.197:22
    kube-1: SSH username: vagrant
    kube-1: SSH auth method: private key
    kube-1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    kube-1:
    kube-1: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    kube-1: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    kube-1:
    kube-1: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    kube-1: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    kube-1: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> kube-1: Machine booted and ready!
==> kube-1: Setting hostname...
```

I would have expected it to look at the Vagrantfile (as per the docs) and assign the IP address that I've specified, even if it was overlapping an existing range (As the docs suggest!)

I've never had problems with vagrant, but then again, I've never needed to statically assign an address... sigh!

Any help investigating / explaining what's going on would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `ip: "172.18.72.210"` is a public IP - You need to select an IP from a [Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) Maybe you wanted to set to `172.16.72.210`

Comment: I believe 172.16.0.0/12 which is allocated to the private IP address space covers the range I'm using, 172.18.72.x so not sure it's this!

Comment: The IP address 172.17.72.210 is provided by AT&T Services, Inc., it's belong to the CDIR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing) 172.0.0.0/12 (range 172.0.0.0 to 172.15.255.255).

Comment: Is that connected with [Vagrant Networking limitation on Hyper-V](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/hyperv/limitations.html)